# Get and save SOAP incoming request (XML) at the server request method ? without handler

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-ws, jbossfuse

I am going to create and install web service(org.apache.cxf) into Jboss fuse as blueprint bundle and this is how my web service implementation concrete class look likes.

I want to access SOAP message at the server request and save request XML (including header, body). Still, i am unable to access SOAP message. How can I achieve this without using handler or interceptor?

I am using **org.apache.cxf.jaxws**

SOAP message is type of **org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage**

```
package ats.emvo.callback;

import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WrappedMessageContext;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.apache.cxf.helpers.IOUtils;
import org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;    

public class ProductService implements IProductService {

    private static final Logger _log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductService.class);


    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext webServiceContext;

    @Override
    public void ConfirmProductMasterDataStatus() {

        try {
        if (webServiceContext != null) {

            WrappedMessageContext mc = (WrappedMessageContext) webServiceContext.getMessageContext();
            if (mc != null) {
                SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) mc.getWrappedMessage();
                if(soapMessage != null) {

                    XMLStreamReader body  = soapMessage.getContent(XMLStreamReader.class); 

                    _log.info("soap message messConInputStream"+ body.toString());
                }else {
                    _log.info("soapMessage  is null");
                }

            }else {
                _log.info("WrappedMessageContext  is null");
            }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            _log.error("Error", e);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do it in your service class, as at that stage the SoapMessage already get consumed.
You have to use an interceptor at very early stage, some code like

```
public class SaveSoapInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

public SaveSoapInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.RECEIVE);
    addBefore(LoggingInInterceptor.class.getName());
}

public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    InputStream is = message.getContent(InputStream.class);
    if (is != null) {
        CachedOutputStream bos = new CachedOutputStream();
        try {
            IOUtils.copy(is, bos);

            bos.flush();
            is.close();
            message.setContent(InputStream.class, bos.getInputStream());
            bos.close();
            String soapMessage = new String(bos.getBytes());// here you get the soap message

    }

}
```

}